# How to catch net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in react js?

Tags: reactjs, axios, try-catch, reactstrap

I am a beginner in react js. I get this error in the console. But I want to display this error to the user. This is my minimalistic code:

```
const [error, setError] = useState("");

try {
  Axios.post('http://10.20.2.3:5000/accounts/login', {      
    email,
    password
  }).then(response =>{
    if (response.status == "201") {
      history.push("/admin/dashboard");
    }
  }).catch(error => {
      if (error.response) {
        setError(error.response.data.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
  }).then(function () {
  });
} catch (e) {
  setError(e.response.data.message);
}


<Alert color="danger" isOpen={ error != ""} fade={true}>
    { error }
</Alert>
```

Should I use a try catch to display such kind of error. I suspect my try catch block is incorrect.

Can anyone help?